# Solving for modular expression?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I stuck somehow on repetition old math exercises...could someone explain the following expression:

$(n!-1)$ mod $ n $

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n | n!$ so $n! \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ and hence $(n! - 1) \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$.

Comment: hmm...cool thx.